# Where can I post a question about Facebook uploader in Picasa?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, scope, site-recommendation

I have a problem with Facebook uploader in Picasa. Where can I post this question?
(SOF sites or in general problem solving forum)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Picasa the desktop application, ask on [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

For the web version and for Facebook aspects of the problem, ask on [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).